# pyexpat ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, xml, dll, module, pythonxy

I use Python 2.7.3 (32bit) on windows XP
when I try to use the standard XML parser in python:

```
from pyexpat import *
```

I get the error:

```
 from pyexpat import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The problem started after I installed [python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/).
when I tried to "fix" python installation with the python [windows installer](http://www.python.org/getit/) it still gives the same error.

**what is the problem?**

Comment: It seems you have a mismatched version of pyexpat.pyd in your DLLs directory.

Comment: So how can I solve that?

Comment: Install to a different directory. Run `python.exe` specifically from that directory. If the import works, then you know the old installation is corrupt.